# Get actual position

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, positioning, beamerposter

Is there any command to get current position in text? 
What do I mean:

```
\the\currentposition
text text text text \newline
\the\currentposition
text text text text \newline
\the\currentposition
```

**Output:**
0pt
text text text text
12pt
text text text text
24pt

Or even better - how to get actual (x,y) position of some text or enviroment (i.e. top left corner of column or block) in the list?

Comment: I'm not sure what your objective is, but with tikz (remember picture and overlay features), you can define a reference point and later create e.g. arrows to it.

Comment: What is your final goal?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  The `tabto` package can do this with horizontal positioning, using, for example, `\tabto*{\TabPrevPos}` to move to that location, with `\TabPrevPos` containing the LaTeX length from left margin to the saved location..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pdfTeX in PDF mode provide `\pdfsavepos`, which stores the current position that can be written to the `.aux` file and used the next TeX run. Also XeTeX and LuaTeX provide this features. There are some limitations:

- XeTeX's right to left mode is somewhat broken.
- Graphics state changes, that do not use the pdfTeX interfaces (`\pdfsetmatrix`, `\pdfsave`, `\pdfrestore`) interfere with the position recording.
- Absolute values are not well defined, thus relative values are preferred.

Package `zref-savepos` of project `zref` provides an interface to the positioning feature:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\newcommand*{\currpos}[1]{%
  \zsavepos{#1}%
  (\zposx{#1}sp, \zposy{#1}sp) =
  (\the\dimexpr\zposx{#1}sp\relax, \the\dimexpr\zposy{#1}sp\relax)%
}

\begin{document}
\leavevmode
\currpos{posA}
text text text text \newline
\currpos{posB}
text text text text \newline
\currpos{posC}
\end{document}
```

Result after two compile runs:

> [image: Result]